# Using Angular components to populate tooltips triggered from D3 visuals

Tags: angular, d3.js, angular9

I have an Angular CLI application that displays a number of D3.v5 visuals. Some of the tooltips I would like to add on those D3 displays are fairly non-trivial, and I would like to make use of the power of Angular's templating and data binding.

The only remotely connected resource I could find is https://github.com/andyperlitch/ngx-d3-tooltip. I checked out the code. It is fairly outdated, relying on D3 v4 and Angular v5.

How would you go about using Angular components as data-driven tooltips from a D3 context ?

Comment: I could probably make something work from the angular perspective, but I'm not overly familiar with d3... do you have any samples anywhere of the d3 charts you'd like to add tooltips to? preferably in the angular context, but I could bring it in if not... are you using any d3 adapter library?

Comment: I'll provide one sample of time series I've been working on. I haven't elected any D3 adapter yet as there does not seem to be anything mature or well supported as far as I can tell.

Comment: @bryan60 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient . It's not a great, nor a finished display, but you can see that there are hooks in place upon hover, and it's all Angular 9 CLI, with just a D3v5 dependency. All code is typescript.

Comment: ok, I started with some other guys stuff that i found, but I can try to adapt to this if what I have isn't clear

Comment: I adapted it to the chart provided: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient-x23a9r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdeviation-chart%2Fdeviation-chart.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a d3 expert, so I started with this: http://bl.ocks.org/williaster/af5b855651ffe29bdca1

and worked my way from there.

Here is the working blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vrq5p6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchart.component.ts

So I wrote a basic component that take in some data and renders a scatter plot with d3.

The component has a tooltip container above the chart container, that looks like this:

```
<div class="tooltip" *ngIf="toolTipTmp && hovered" [ngStyle]="ttPos">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="toolTipTmp.tmp; context: {$implicit: hovered}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

the component has corresponding properties:

```
  @ContentChild(ChartTooltipDirective)
  toolTipTmp: ChartTooltipDirective

  hovered?: any
  ttPos = {
    "left.px": 0,
    "top.px": 0
  }
```

the content child here is a simple directive that exposes a template:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[chart-tooltip]"
})
export class ChartTooltipDirective {
  constructor(public tmp: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

then the render function links into these on the mouse enter and mouse leave functions:

```
  var tipMouseover = (d) => {
      this.hovered = d;
      this.ttPos["left.px"] = d3.event.pageX + 15;
      this.ttPos["top.px"] = d3.event.pageY - 28;
  };
  // tooltip mouseout event handler
  var tipMouseout = (d) => {
      this.hovered = undefined;
  };

  ....

    .on("mouseover", tipMouseover)
    .on("mouseout", tipMouseout);
```

basically it just sets the hovered element and the position of the tooltip.

The concept here is that you set whatever element is hovered and set the tooltip's position on the component, and use that info to reveal and position the tooltip, then you feed the hovered element into the the template context, and use some template defined as a content child of your chart component, so you can define whatever template you like.

you use it in your template pretty easily:

```
<my-chart [data]="data" xLabel="Sugar" yLabel="Calories">
  <ng-template chart-tooltip let-d>
    {{d.cereal}}
    <br>
    <span>{{d.manufacturer}}</span>
    <br>
    <b>{{d.sugar}}</b> sugar, <b>{{d.calories}}</b> calories
  </ng-template>
</my-chart>
```

just apply your directive and write up your tooltip template.  This way, you have pretty much the full power of angular templating and components for your tooltips.

I tried to make this as generic as possible, but again, not a d3 expert.

EDIT:

here it is adapted to the chart you provided:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-deviation-chart-gradient-x23a9r?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdeviation-chart%2Fdeviation-chart.component.ts

Comment: Hey - this is really great... Two questions: 1) what does converting that ng-template for the tooltip to a component entail ? 2) I fail to understand the magic of `let-d` ?

Comment: 1. not positive i get you, but I think you just want to put the component you want in the template like `<ng-template chart-tooltip let-d><my-component [item]="d"></my-component></ng-template>` 2. `let-d` is the `$implicit` context set on the `templatOutlet` directive. so it's whatever data you've set as that implicit context, in this case, we're setting the hovered item.  you can add more context if you wish like `context: {$implicit: hovered, somethingElse: other}` which you could access on the template as `let-whatever="somethingElse` .. you've likely seen similar syntax in an `ngFor`

Comment: thanks, that was really quick from your part. What single best Angular resource would you recommend for me to take my Angular to the next level ?

Comment: I've read some good articles from angular university... he's a little into ngrx for my taste but his info is solid and he touches next level topics... but i've also just been writing angular since v1 beta